# Eclipse error syntax checking

Tags: eclipse

How to turn ON automatic error checking inside Java code within the Eclipse IDE? I have already checked the "Build Automatically", but it still does not check my error when I purposely throw away my semicolons. Need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you configure your folder to be the source folder?It should be included in the java build path (`The project properties--> java build path --> source` ) ? Eclipse will only checks the java syntax error automatically for the folders that are included in the java build path.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to turn on anything, it should work out-of-the-box. The only case I can think of when it might not work are when editing java files outside any project. Are you sure that the java files you're editing are located in a source folder of an open project?